# Getting PG Error hard to debug when using delayed_job on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, delayed-job

I am trying to use heroku and appear to be getting a Postgres error but don't have enough information to know what to fix.

The error is below, and it looks like it is trying to run delayed_job:

```
> PGError: ERROR:  value too long for
> type character varying(255) : UPDATE
> "delayed_jobs" SET "updated_at" =
> '2010-09-12 01:06:59.354515', "last_e
> rror" = E'undefined method `subject''
> for #<YAML::Object:0x2b19faeca308>
```

Here is how I invoke it from a cron.rake:

```
    Delayed::Job.enqueue SomeMailJob.new(contact,contact_email)
```

SomeMailJob is defined through this file:

```
 class SomeMailJob < Struct.new(:contact, :contact_email) 
   def perform
     OutboundMailer.deliver_campaign_email(contact,contact_email)
   end
 end
```

It "looks" like the database for delayed_jobs is trying to be updated with something funky but I have no idea what that could be.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postgres error is occurring when the delayed job worker process tries to store the result of running the job (which was a separate error, btw).

Check your delayed_jobs table, specifically the `last_error` column. It should be a `text` column but it looks like yours is a `string`.

Comment: Hi, how do I check it -- I used the migration built into the plugin so that seems odd it would be off....let me check what the migration table was....

Comment: yes the migration for the plugin makes last_error string instead of text....I can change the migration -- but maybe should let the guys who own the plugin know...

Comment: Hmm...looks like they wrote it that way:  http://github.com/pedro/delayed_job  -- but they put a note to make the change just as you suggested, so will give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the underlying error is from calling "subject" on an object that doesn't have that method defined.

Comment: How can I figure out what that object is, it doesn't give me enough information to figure that out (I don't know why it would be calling that method)....

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to enter a value, which has more than 255 chars in to a column which has the max chars 255.

cheers

sameera